# Attempt to read from null array but array contains several filenames

Tags: android

My app worked fine but after a reinstall I got the error that "attempt to get length of null array", while my dob folder is full of files that starting with pi_. Now I get files - Null.

Can anybody help what the error can be?

Thanks

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/dob");

    if (path.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Dob folder exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Dob folder does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    File[] files = path.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "files length: " + files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        piStarters = new String[files.length];
        int db = 0;

        for (File file : files) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ":" + file.toString() + ":", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (file.getName().startsWith("pi_")) {

                piStarters[db] = file.getName();
                Toast.makeText(this, "I need this (pistarter): " + piStarters[db], Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                db++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "files - Null ", Toast
                .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: have you implemented runtime permissions ?

Comment: yes my manifest file contains:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: what is your android OS?

Comment: Android 6.0 is the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You required to implement [`Requesting Permissions at Run Time`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to access the phone storage **otherwise android OS marshmallow and above won't allow your app to access storage**

So you need to implement the runtime permission model for storage access

[`Follow the link for an example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding